# How to create an empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I saw this line of code from a book, what does that mean? After that, I print portfolio, it is just a underscore, but it is not empty DataFrame.

```
portfolio = portfolio = pd.DataFrame()
```

Comment: The double assignment is a typo in the book; a harmless one because you just assign back over the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing the result of how an empty DataFrame is **displayed**,. The DataFrame is in fact empty; you can see this better using a `print` or checking the `empty` attribute.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()

display(df)
#_

print(df)
#Empty DataFrame
#Columns: []
#Index: []

df.empty
#True
```

Answer (score 1):

`portfolio = pd.DataFrame()` does create an empty DataFrame where you can then add columns like e.g. `portfolio['my_col'] = np.zeros(10)` . I'm note sure I understand your question, could you give some more information?

Comment: Thanks Adrien, Yes portfolio = pd.DataFrame() create an empty dataframe, then what is this one?  portfolio = portfolio = pd.DataFrame()? I don't understand it.

Comment: Here is does the same as portfolio = pd.DataFrame() because portfolio is called two times identically. But you could e.g. write portfolio = portfolio2 = pd.DataFrame() which is the same as portfolio = pd.DataFrame() and portfolio2 = pd.DataFrame()

Comment: Thanks Adrien, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to assign a dataframe. Like this --> portfolio = pd.DataFrame()

So it is almost as the way you wrote. Only need to assign once and remove the repeated "portfolio ="